# What is the Span of all LI Eigenvectors associated with Transformation T Called?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider transformation T (given by transformation Matrix A), and the corresponding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors.

*For reference, the definitions im working with are:*

1. **Eigenspace:** *The set of all eigenvectors of T corresponding to the same eigenvalue, together with the zero vector, is called an eigenspace, or the characteristic space of T associated with that eigenvalue.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)
2. **Eigenbasis:** *If a set of eigenvectors of T forms a basis of the domain of T, then this basis is called an eigenbasis.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

**Question:** What do we call the span of all Linearly Independent Eigenvectors associated with the transformation T.

For example if the eigenvectors do not form a basis of $\Bbb C^n$ does their span still have a name. Equivalent to the name (Eigenspace) given to span of Eigenvectors associated with a single Eigenvalue.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi I've been using the site for a while, and try and follow the unwritten rules. I have no idea why this would be voted down. If anyone could clarify that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Your (2) is misleading: not every $A$ has enough LI eigenvectors to produce a  basis. If it does then clearly they generate the whole space.

Comment: I didn't downvote it or vote to close it, but the reason for closure is "lack of clarity or other details".

Comment: @Corm For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, an "eigenbasis" is a basis of $\Bbb C^n$ whose elements are all eigenvectors. So, if $A$ has an eigenbasis, then the span of all eigenvectors in its eigenbasis would be $\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: Okay thank you that's helpful! And Ben Grossmann's edit was helpful. Do you understand / have any idea about my question. The first two points were just meant to give the definitions I was working with...I'll rephrase 2) so it is more precise.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you! So we don't give it a special name, because I suppose it is still just $\Bbb C^n$ but using the Eigenvectors to form the coordinate system. 

But what if we don't have enough LI eigenvectors to form $\Bbb C^n$ does the Linear Combination of Eigenvectors associated with the Matrix A, not have it's own special word? The same way Eigenspace, is the span of Eigenvectors associated with just one Eigenvalue?

Comment: @Corm It does not have its own special word, no

Comment: Okay I see thank you for you time! I have edited my question anyway, so it's a better source for future reference now, thank you!